# Strange choice of related question

Tags: bug

I was looking at [Why did Churchill become the PM of Britain during WWII instead of Lord Halifax?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/62594/12622).

One of the *related questions* presented was [When did Aurochs (large wild cattle) become extinct in Britain?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/42930/12622)

What is the relation?

Answer (score 8):

This is the result of an automated algorithm, see [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. At least both questions are about [britain](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/britain); you see some of the other related questions are about [world-war-two](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-two).

Comment: I agree that the tags are probably the reason. Still, its pretty amusing that of the 50+ questions with that tag, the algorithm chose that one.

Comment: @T.E.D.: LOL That's the best chuckle I've had all day.